# How to bind javascript code of TWA to native functions?

Tags: javascript, android, twa

I am currently trying to enrich my PWA (Progressive Web App). My PWA is an app which works with jQuery / HTML5 and it works.
Now I want to build a trusted web activity (TWA) as I want to go directly to the newest technology (not the WebView from Android Studio, as TWA uses Chrome as Engine and I really like Chrome). Also, I have a request which I can not make via PWA, only via native functions (phone tracking).

Now my plan is, that my TWA can communicate with the native app. Is there a way so that I can call in the TWA a JS function and this JS function is linked to a native function?

Comment: do you have found a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to call a native function from JavaScript when using Trusted Web Activity.